# How to determine if ZonedDateTime is "today"?

Tags: java, java-time

I assumed this would have already been asked, but I couldn't find [anything](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+java.time+today+is%3Aquestion).

Using `java.time` what is the best way to determine if a given `ZonedDateTime` is "today"?

I've come up with at least two possible solutions. I'm not sure if there are any loopholes or pitfalls with these approaches. Basically the idea is to let `java.time` figure it out and not do any math myself:

```
/**
 * @param zonedDateTime a zoned date time to compare with "now".
 * @return true if zonedDateTime is "today".
 * Where today is defined as year, month, and day of month being equal.
 */
public static boolean isZonedDateTimeToday1(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();

    return now.getYear() == zonedDateTime.getYear()
            && now.getMonth() == zonedDateTime.getMonth()
            && now.getDayOfMonth() == zonedDateTime.getDayOfMonth();
}


/**
 * @param zonedDateTime a zoned date time to compare with "now".
 * @return true if zonedDateTime is "today". 
 * Where today is defined as atStartOfDay() being equal.
 */
public static boolean isZoneDateTimeToday2(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime atStartOfToday = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay();

    LocalDateTime atStartOfDay = zonedDateTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay();

    return atStartOfDay == atStartOfToday;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if the value is "today" in the timezone of the value, or in the default timezone of the JVM?

Comment: You should not say ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(). It's always a date of the current day. Meaning it's always today.

Comment: First, make it absolutely explicit what you mean by "today"!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you mean today in the default time zone:

```
return zonedDateTime.toLocalDate().equals(LocalDate.now());

//you may want to clarify your intent by explicitly setting the time zone:
return zonedDateTime.toLocalDate().equals(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

If you mean today in the same timezone as the ZonedDateTime:

```
return zonedDateTime.toLocalDate().equals(LocalDate.now(zonedDateTime.getZone()));
```

Comment: But `now()` in the default zone may be a different date than the date in the value zone.

Comment: @Andreas typed too fast - thanks. I believe the op's example uses the default time zone too.

Comment: As good style, I'd recommend using `ZoneId.systemDefault()` in the first one, as otherwise I'd presume that it was a mistake, and you meant to use the zone from the `ZonedDateTime` as in the second one.